# Why can't i create an inherited model?

Tags: django, inheritance, model

Im a newbie in Django and have model inheritance problem.

My models:

```
class Interaction(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    lieu = models.ForeignKey(Lieu, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='...')
    acces_libre = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Heros(Interaction):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)

    #############   Attributs   ##########
    corps = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    coeur = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    esprit = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom


class Personnage(Interaction):

    # Attributs  
    corps = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    coeur = models.IntegerField(default=50)
    esprit = models.IntegerField(default=50)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
```

My migrations:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Interaction',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('nom', models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)),
                ('description', models.TextField(default='...')),
                ('acces_libre', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
            ],
        ),

migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Heros',
            fields=[
                ('interaction_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='aventures.Interaction')),
                ('corps', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('coeur', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('esprit', models.IntegerField(default=0)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            bases=('aventures.interaction',),
        ),

migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Personnage',
            fields=[
                ('interaction_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='aventures.Interaction')),
                ('corps', models.IntegerField(default=50)),
                ('coeur', models.IntegerField(default=50)),
                ('esprit', models.IntegerField(default=50)),
            ],
            bases=('aventures.interaction',),
        ),
migrations.AddField(
            model_name='interaction',
            name='lieu',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='aventures.Lieu'),
        ),
```

If i try to creeate a heros in django admin i have:

```
no such column: aventures_heros.interaction_ptr_id
```

If i try to create a Personnage:

```
no such table: aventures_personnage
```

I tried to delete my migrations but it didn't work.
I did delete all my old instance from my old models, it didn't work too...
I don't anderstand why it doesn't works can somone help me?

Thanks :)

Comment: DId you *migrate*?

Comment: Yes, i did. And tried makmigrations then migrate many times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to share fields without having to repeat them in your model. In this case, it is highly recommended to *avoid* **concrete** inheritance, and instead use **abstract** inheritance.

You can do this simply like so:

```
class Interaction(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    lieu = models.ForeignKey(Lieu, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='...')
    acces_libre = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

After doing this, you can run `makemigrations` and `migrate` for this to take effect

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

Comment: Ok i ll try this. But it's more that i want to be able to make a relation with all my models in one time using Interaction, like: models.foreignkey(Interaction...) and not one foreignkey for all childrens of Interaction. I did read it's not possible to use an abstract model i m right? Or is there a besser way?